# Windows Reverse Lookup Zone & Subnetting

Tags: windows-server-2008, reverse-dns

We have a /23 subnet that we are trying to create a reverse lookup zone on our Windows server.

172.16.150.0/23

Unfortunately we can't add a subnet mask.  None of the links I've found thus far make it clear on how to add this subnet.  Any help would be appreciated.

This link seems promising but I am not sure of the exact syntax within the MMC.

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/174419

Thanks!

Not sure if this is the best practice, but we ended up just added two zones:

172.16.150.0
172.16.151.0

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174419

Comment: Would the syntax be: 0/23.150.16.172.in-addr.arpa or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, your subnet mask for a `/23` network would be `255.255.254.0`, and [it looks like Microsoft would recommend using a reverse zone of `16.172.in-addr.arpa`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richpec/archive/2008/08/24/how-to-consolidate-many-reverse-dns-zones-into-fewer-larger-reverse-dns-zones.aspx) for that.  Seems weird, but I checked on our DNS server, and our reverse lookup zones are setup that way as well, and we have no problems with it.

If you had a large number of hosts in the 172.16.0.0/16 subnet, or served different subnets within that from different DNS servers, you'd want to break it out to keep lookup times from getting too long or going to a wrong DNS server, but it typically won't matter either way, unless you manage a very large network.